# Notification in Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created a notification for android wear. Notification is coming out properly. I have also added addAction to notification. I have two issues:

1. I am not sure why I am getting a three slide pages (Three dots in the bottom),

   ```
    a. Notificaiton text
    b. A black background image (second slide)
    c. Add action button (third slide)
   ```
2. I am trying click on the notification to open a new intent it is not working:

Here is the code I have tried:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Wear.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
int notificationId = 001;
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backgroundwatch);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launchericon)
     .setContentTitle("Mail ME")
     .setContentText("Are you in need of help?? Click or slide to request help!")
     .setLargeIcon(background)
     .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(background))
     .addAction(R.drawable.launchericon,"Help", contentIntent);
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: in your question you ask about android war, and android wear in your description, what are you talking about ;) ;)

Comment: Have you tried a .show() method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, when you use `BigPictureStyle` it is shown as 3 pages on Android Wear:

1. Usual notification with text
2. Only image from `.bigPicture(...)` call
3. `Open` action

Check, which bitmap is actually here `R.drawable.backgroundwatch`, because you reassign `background` variable twice:

```
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backgroundwatch);
```

Comment: my it was a typo. I have initialized only once. How to solve this issue?

Comment: What's your main issue? 1) you don't need 2nd page or 2) instead of image, you see black rectangle?

Comment: There are two issues: 1. I am getting three pages? I should get only two according to the code above. (second page is just empty with background image) 2. I am not able to click on the notification to get some action done?

Comment: 1. seems like having 3 pages for `BigPictureStyle` is ok. I get the same. And it seems to be useful.

Comment: 2. Have you set [`android.app.Notification.WearableExtender#setContentAction(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.WearableExtender.html#setContentAction(int)) ?